# Выполнение скрипта после загрузки всех компонентов страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как реализовать выполнение скрипта после загрузки таких компонентов, как изображения? Видимо, конструкция `$(function(){ /* ... */ });` реализует выполнение скрипта после загрузки самих DOM-элементов, а не их отрисовки браузером и не подключением всех фоновых изображений и так далее.
Как решить эту проблему?

Вот пример:
[image: aga]

Включите на [этом сайте](https://vostoksisters.github.io) тротлинг и обновите страницу без кеша (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>).
Тротлинг (ограничение скоростной способности сети) делается так (в Google Chrome):

1. <kbd>F12</kbd> (инспектор)
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (включение мобильного вида)
3. Вверху справа выберите какое-нибудь ограничение, например, Regular 2G.

И увидите, что страница ещё прогружается, но скрипт уже работает, и если зайти щёлкнуть на меню, выбрать категорию из списка, то картинки на фоне ещё не загрузились.

Может, это и нормально, видимо, для JavaScript и jQuery, но когда везде пишут, что скрипт будет работать после загрузки страницы, я именно это и подумал... Что он будет работать после полной загрузки страницы. Как быть?

Comment: `$('img').load(function() {...});` ?

Comment: @Yuri, а конструкция, которую я написал, не гарантирует загрузку вложенных элементов? Зачем тогда исполнение $(document).ready();, если конструкция ничего не делает вообще? Я не понимаю,  это такая огромная шутка на весь мир?

Comment: `$(document).ready();` подрозумивает загрузку DOM элементов, а не самих картинок. Что бы отследить загрузку самих картинок, используют `load`

Comment: @Yuri, если я пишу `$('body').load()`, то скрипт вообще не выполняется по всей видимости... Ваш пример не корректен в моем случае, потому что "всплески" заданы как `div` элементы с `background: url(...)`. 
Вот конструкция моего [скрипта](https://github.com/VostokSisters/vostoksisters.github.io/blob/master/assets/js/_logic.js) в репозитории

Comment: @Yuri, вот такая конструкция: `$( window ).load(function() { ... })` также не работает, хотя а она в [официальной в справке](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) указана и чёрным по белому там всё написано...

Comment: А вы погрузите все картинки на одно полотно, тогда они будут разом прогружатьтся и меньше будет таких хреней

Comment: @Yuri, а какая разница, разом или не разом? Спрайтами или нет, их всё равно грузить придется и такая фигня всё равно будет.
Спрайтовый подход призван снизить количество обращений на сервер, а это мне побарабану пока что, пока я юзаю гитхаб)

Comment: Если все в одной картинке, то они прогрузятся все разом и не будет скочков

Comment: @Yuri, да господи. Неужели нет контроля исполнения скрипта JS при загрузке всего содержимого страницы? Чушь полная. Даже `$( window ).load(function() { ... })` не работает, который в официальной справке указан. Можешь зайти на сайт и отыскать его в папке assets, он просто не исполняется...

Comment: Что вы от меня хотите? Я предлагаю решение проблемы с прогрузкой!

Comment: @Yuri, я это проверил выводом в консоль сообщения. Просто по факту не исполняется вообще. Я думал это из-за использования клиентского галповского Browser Sync, поскольку у него там свои скрипты для контроля содержимого, но даже когда загрузил скрипт на сайт и Jekyll всё пересобрал, всё равно не работает. Расстроен ):

Comment: @VostokSisters К сожаленью ваши вопросы и ответы невысокого качества, потому что у вас нету минимальных и самодостаточных примеров. В случае чего, вы посылаете на сайт с кучей кода и не понятно почему мы должны в нём разбираться.

Comment: @VostokSisters Вы, видимо, не понимаете цели этого сайта. Это не ваша личная служба поддержки. Это формат "вопрос-ответа", но так, чтобы этим могли пользоваться тысячи людей. Чтобы по образу и подобию вопроса и ответа решали свои проблемы, а не каждый просил помочь с его проектом и каждый задавал вопрос.

Comment: @VostokSisters Минусы значат, что ваши вопросы/ответы не несут пользы для других людей. И всё. Ничего личного, просто субъективная оценка вашего вклада в базу знаний.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Нашел решение обычным гуглением. В очередной раз убеждаюсь, что jQuery сильно переоценена как многофункциональная библиотека. 
Задача решается следующим кодом:

```
window.onload = {
 function_name()
}
```

А jQuery пора обновить метод. Он не работает вообще никак. Использовал методы, что указаны на [официальном сайте](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), а именно: `$( window ).load(function() { ... })`, но как и сказал, такой код нерабочий и ничего не делает. Если дадите разобраться почему не работает, буду благодарен)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51394/discussion-on-answer-by-vostoksisters------).